# How to get shadow on a floating button in react native

Tags: react-native

**What I am trying to achieve**: A floating rounded button with plus symbol, with blue background, and blue shadow.

**What I have tried**: I am able to get a rounded floating button with plus symbol

**What I am not able to attain**: Shadow for it with blue color

---

**Code:**

```
<View style={historyStyles.AvatarView}>
          <Avatar
            size={"medium"}
            rounded
            icon={{ name: "plus", type: "font-awesome" }}
            overlayContainerStyle={{
              backgroundColor: this.props.theameColors.PRIMARY
            }}
            onPress={this.gotoFeed}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
          />
        </View>
```

**With above code I got the result:** (I am not able to get shadow)

[image]

***Note:*** I can't use third party library

Comment: can you share your code in expo snack

Answer (score 0):

RN allows very customizable shadows for iOS, but for Android it's pretty limited. Basically this are the available shadow props:

```
          // shadow props for ios
          shadowColor: '#000',
          shadowOffset: {
            width: 5,
            height: 5,
          },
          shadowOpacity: 0.2,
          shadowRadius: 10,
          // shadow props for android
          elevation: 0.4
```

you can also use [this web tool](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/).

So, there is no easy way to do that in Android, you can use some libs that achieve this with svg rendering.